# What tools do you use to administer analyze and otherwise manage your AWS SimpleDB(s)?

Tags: amazon-simpledb

I'm working on OS X, so it has to at least work there, but I generally prefer tools that support multiple platforms.

It's possible that I'm being too picky, but the [JavaScript demo](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=149) that Amazon provides doesn't quite seem like enough...

Comment: I started using the trial of SDB Explorer (http://www.sdbexplorer.com/), which is satisfactory, but I'm still wondering if there are any decent FOSS tools available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally wound up stumbling over [this list](http://blog.cloudberrylab.com/2009/01/blog-post-amazon-simpledb-3rd-party.html) of SimpleDB administrative tools.

For whatever it's worth, I'm about to try out the Firefox plugin.

Answer (score 2):

[Mindscape SimpleDB Management Tools](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/simpledbtools/default.aspx) is a great add-in for Visual Studio that lets you query, create and generally manage your SimpleDB instances visually. You will need to be a Visual Studio user to get the benefit of it as it must be hosted in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm working on OS X - so no Visual Studio for me. I'll update the question right now.